# KeyError in Django-SocialRegistration

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-socialregistration, but I got KeyError.

My code on view.py is just as following:

```
def login_new(request):
    return render_to_response(
        'login_new.html', dict(
        facebook=FacebookProfile.objects.all(),
        twitter=TwitterProfile.objects.all(),
        openid=OpenIDProfile.objects.all(),
        linkedin=LinkedInProfile.objects.all(),
        github=GithubProfile.objects.all(),
        foursquare=FoursquareProfile.objects.all(),
        tumblr=TumblrProfile.objects.all(),
        instagram=InstagramProfile.objects.all(),
        ), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and on the template file (login_new.html)

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>

{% load openid %}
{% openid_form 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id' 'login/with/google.png' %}

</body>
</html>
```

The error is occuring at

```
{% openid_form 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id' 'login/with/google.png' %}
```

and at /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in

```
get_response response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

In the [Note on sessions section of the document](http://django-socialregistration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#note-on-sessions), there is following statement:

"When starting the registration process, all the user’s temporary data is stored in the user’s session. If you’re developing on 127.0.0.1:8000, you will have to set your callback URLs to begin with 127.0.0.1:8000 too or you will get a new session when returning to the site and socialregistration won’t be able to find the temporary data and subsequently throw a KeyError."

I think this may be the cause of this error, but I don't know what can I do from this statement. Which file can I modify? What command can I execute?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the default site (from the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/)) is pointing to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. It defaults to `www.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
Unfortunately, I modified Sites value to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ from admin interface, but nothing changed...